# Проблема с разметкой дисков при установке Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файловая-система, gparted

В данный момент у меня уже есть установленная windows 7. Когда то я отрезал от диска д память и присоединял к диску с с помощью Acronis Disk Director из винды, не из биоса. Один раз всё прошло успешно, но был случай когда акронис вылетел с ошибкой, и мне еле удалось каким-то образом восстановить диск без форматирования и система стартонула нормально.

Сейчас мне нужно установить Ubuntu Linux рядом с уже установленной виндой. Есть у меня диск, почти пустой - sda1, по всей логике там должен быть системный раздел но у меня диск С находится на sda2. И диск Д каким то образом находится в оболочке extended.

Если я пытаюсь отрезать от sda1 кусок и создать там extended для линуха, вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как мне правильно разметить (возможно исправить эту кривую разметку) без последствий для винды и корректно установить Linux?

[image: ..]

Comment: По опыту могу сказать следующее: чем такого лечить - проще нового родить. Переразметь всё заново (надумаешь - могу подсказать более-менее оптимальный вариант). Разделы подвигать конечно можно, но винда потом может выскочить с ошибкой про `winload.exe`. А так @LebedevAleksey рассказал почему возникает ошибка на скрине.

Comment: @donRumata есть вариант переразметить не повредя файлы и вообще загрузку винды?

Comment: Да, но всё равно бэкап важных файлов лучше сделать на отдельный физический диск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в существующий extended раздел новых логических разделов (отпиленных от Local Disk D)

Answer (score 2):

У Вас сейчас уже создано 4 основных раздела sda1, sda2, sda4, sda5 это максимальное количество основных разделов, дальше можно создавать только дополнительные разделы (extended).
Вы можете создать extended раздел sda5 для Linux.
Систему поставить в extended раздел можно, вот только загрузчик должен находится в primary разделе. Отформатируйте раздел sda1 и поставьте туда загрузчик GRUB в настройках укажите ему что у Вас две системы Windows в sda2 и Linux в sda5.

Comment: Кстати, форматировать пробовал на винде этот почти пустой диск, выскакивает "Windows unable to complete the format"

Comment: Вам сначала необходимо там создать раздел и как я уже говорил это должен быть extendex раздел.
Я тоже советую Вам создать новую структуру диска и все переустановить.
Например:
sda1 - основной раздел с загрузчиком.
sda2 - основной раздел с windows.
sda3 - раздел подкачки для linux
sda4 - основной раздел с linux.
Дальше можете создавать extended разделы для данных.

Comment: Окей, а как мне убрать существующий extended, оставив при этом логический раздел, от которого я отпилю где то 50 гб, и из них сделаю extended?

Comment: Форматировать можно прямо из под Windows и назначать разделы - https://www.partitionwizard.com

Comment: @avparfiriev вот из под винды форматировал акронисом и пожалел

Comment: для работы использую эту утилиту, проблем не возникало на Windows 7 ent